# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Producer force producer.flush

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am creating a kafka streams/in-out kind of application.
Sample code looks like the following

```
private MessageChannel output;

public void process(List<String> input) {
--somelogic
output.send()
}
```

Based on  my understanding, kafka buffers the messages before sending them out. Now in case the app crashes / container crashes, there is a possibility of losing the buffered messages.

How can we ensure that messages are actually sent out

(something like KafkaTemplate.flush() here ?)

**EDIT**
Based on the suggestion by Gary Russell, we should set the FLUSH header on the last message.

Follow up question -
Given the last send method call will become a blocking call because of the blocking nature of the kafkaProducer.flush() method, if there are exceptions thrown during the sending process of the kafka message (e.g. io exception/ auth exception) will they be raised in the same method context ?

e.g. in the following code will the kafka sender exception be caught in the catch block ?

```
public void process(List<String> input) {
--somelogic
  try {
  Message<?> message = //
  message.setHeader(KafkaIntegrationHeaders.FLUSH, true);
  output.send()
 }
catch(Exception e) {
  e.printstacktrace()
}
}
```

Comment: Kafka only buffers output if `linger.ms` is increased from its default 0.

Comment: in general linger.ms would be > 0 to reduce network traffic, here i am trying to ensure that messages are sent before completing the processing for the batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` has a property:

```java
/**
 * Specify a SpEL expression that evaluates to a {@link Boolean} to determine whether
 * the producer should be flushed after the send. Defaults to looking for a
 * {@link Boolean} value in a {@link KafkaIntegrationHeaders#FLUSH} header; false if
 * absent.
 * @param flushExpression the {@link Expression}.
 */
public void setFlushExpression(Expression flushExpression) {
```

Currently, the binder doesn't support customizing this property.

However, if you are sending `Message<?>`s, you can set the `KafkaIntegrationHeaders.FLUSH` header to `true` on the last message in the batch.

Comment: thanks, one more question - so the last send method call becomes a blocking call right ? (because of flush on the last message)

Comment: Flush on the producer will block, yes; see the javadocs for `KafkaProducer.flush()` for more information.

Comment: Updated the question with follow-up question, can you pls answer that as well

Comment: Yes, see the javadocs; flush will wait on all the outstanding futures to complete; if there is a failure, the exception is thrown to the caller.